# Expansion of Space-Time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Imagine you want (without General Relativity) to describe the expansion of a universe (I'm doing this just for practicing my differential equation skills).

First of all, we will have to find the equation or equations that describe this expansion.
$$
\rho (t) = \frac{E}{V(t)} \rightarrow \rho(t) V(t) = E
$$
We will assume that $E$ is constant, hence:
$$
\rho'(t)V(t) + \rho(t)V'(t) = 0 \\
\frac{\rho'}{\rho} = -\frac{V'}{V}
$$
Now we will have to try  to find an expresion for $V(t)$:
$$
V''(t) = -\kappa \rho(t) - \mu V(t) + \Lambda
$$

### Terms In the Equation:

The "$-\kappa \rho(t)$" term, just accounts for the atraction of gravity.

The "$\Lambda$" term, is the dark energy, a repulsive "force" that balances the atracction of gravity.

The "$-\mu V(t)$" is the stiffnes of space-time (how easily can you deformate space time).

Now we can find an expression for $\rho'(t)$ and $\rho(t)$ in terms of $V(t)$:

$$
\rho(t) = -\frac{V''(t) + \mu V(t) - \Lambda}{\kappa} \\
V'''(t) = - \kappa \rho'(t) - \mu V'(t) \rightarrow \rho'(t) =  -\frac{V'''(t) + \mu V'(t)}{\kappa}
$$

Substitute in the previous equation and we have:
$$
\frac{V'''(t) + \mu V'(t)}{V'(t) + \mu V(t) - \Lambda} = -\frac{V'(t)}{V(t)}
$$

How would you solve this equations? Don't know where to start.

**Note:** As you can see I didn't use GR. I just wanted to see if I could (kind of) describe the expansion of the universe just with classical non-relativistic physics, just for fun! This is mainly a physics question, but as the thing I want to know is how to solve the equation I would rather ask here.

Comment: The equation $V''(t)=-\kappa\rho(t)-\mu V(t)+\Lambda$ looks strange. Suppose there is no gravity and no dark energy then $V''(t)=-\mu V(t)$ with solution being $\cos(\sqrt{\mu}t)$ for example.

Comment: From $$V''(t) = -\kappa \rho(t) - \mu V(t) + \Lambda$$ and $$\rho(t)=\frac{E}{V(t)}$$ we get $$V''(t) V(t)=-\kappa E-\mu V(t)^2+\Lambda V(t),$$ which seems very hard to solve. In GR, the global geometric properties of solutions to the Einstein field equations are, in general, very complex. Making the simplifying assumption of isotropy everywhere implies that the energy-stress tensor and metric tensor take a special form. In the end, one obtains a FLRW metric (cf. for example [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/668534/233512).)

Comment: The FLRW metric only depends on the sign of the curvature $k\in\{-1,0,1\}$ as well as the scale parameter $a(t)$. The latter satisfies the *Friedmann equations*: $$\left(\frac{\dot a}{a}\right)^2 = \frac{8 \pi G}{3} \rho - \frac{kc^2}{a^2}\ + \frac{\Lambda c^2}{3}.$$

Comment: For example in the case $\text{pressure}=0=\Lambda=k$, one can derive that the solution is $a(t)=Ct^{2/3}$, giving the *Einstein-De-Sitter universe.*

Comment: (Actually the $a(t)\propto t^{2/3}$ is also preserved more generally in the matter-dominated stages of flat FLRW solutions to the EFE.)